# horizontal scroll bar on opera-mini even after using media query

Tags: html, css, opera-mini

Hi I am making a responsive [site](http://www.findyogi.com/q), and using `media query` for that following is my code:
([LINK](http://www.findyogi.com/q))

```
@media screen and (max-width:960px){
/*Here Goes my code for screen size 960px */
}

@media screen and (max-width:700px){
    /*Here Goes my code for screen size 700px */
}
@media screen and (max-width:625px){
    /*Here Goes my code for screen size 700px */
}
```

I have given `min-width` to body as `250px`

But still I am getting a horizontal scroll on Opera-mini, is there any other hack that I should I use to make media query work on opera mini.. this is the link if want to see on your opera mini mobile [LINK](http://www.findyogi.com/q)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.You can make your body tag's `overflow to hidden`

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your site's head tag, may be it will work:
 `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>` 
is it working ?